# Android: Random Activity in a Quiz Application

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a **Random Activity Tutorial** anywhere but nothing really works for my application.

After answering the quiz and clicking the next, I want to launch to a random activity.

Here is the code I made in one of the Quiz Activities **but has no Random Codes yet**:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class G2g1Activity extends Activity {


private Button btnOK;
private Button btnHint;
private EditText inputtxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_g2g1);


    inputtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.g2g1_et);
    btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.g2g1_btnOK);
    btnHint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.g2g1_btnHint);

     btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
       {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View ContentView) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String name;

             name=inputtxt.getText().toString();

             if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Cash"))
             {

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CASH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               Intent i = new Intent (G2g1Activity.this, G2g2Activity.class);
               startActivity(i);
               finish();

             }
             else
             {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, wrong answer. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }     


            };
            });

         btnHint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View ContentView) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Money, owned money, type + Currency, Coins, Exchange", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            };
            });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a random number from the number of activities you have. Then use `switch` statement to start the activity with the random number.

For instance,

```
int min = 1;
int max = 10;

Random r = new Random();
int random = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min; //+1 if max is inclusive
```

Then `switch`:

```
switch(random) {

case 1: //Activity A
break;

case 2: //Activity B
break;

case 3: //Activity C
break;

.
.
.
}
```

Comment: How can I stop it?
When I already took 5 items (activities).

Comment: What you can do is put all the generated numbers in an array and every time a new number is generated, check it against the array to see if the number is present in it. If not, go ahead with that number, otherwise, ignore it and regenerate another number. But make sure you keep updating the array once you've used a number.

Comment: I'm sorry I am new in android. I don't actually how to code those things. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code where i used default 5 activities in string array.

```
String[] title = new String[] { "Activity1.class", "Activity2.class","Activity3.class","Activity4.class","Activity5.class"};

public String getRandomAct(){
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
        return title[randomInt-1];

        }

Intent i= new Intent(this,getRandomAct())
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

make a string array with names of all the activities

```
    String activities[]={"activity1","activity2"...}
```

then create a random integer and select randomly one of the string variables then adding it to the new intent by :

```
    Random random=new Random;
    String randomstr=activities[random.nextInt(activities.length-1)];
Class   ourClass=Class.forName("com.example.quiz."+randomstr);
    Intent i= new Intent(this.currentactivity,ourClass):
```